# Flink: how does the parallelism set in the Jobmanager UI relate to task slots?

Tags: parallel-processing, bigdata, apache-flink, distributed-computing

Let's say I have 8 task managers with 16 task slots. If I submit a job using the Jobmanager UI and set the parallelism to 8, do I only utilise 8 task slots?

What if I have 8 task managers with 8 slots, and submit the same job with a parallelism of 8? Is it exactly the same thing? Or is there a difference in the way the data is processed?

Thank you.

Comment: From looking at metrics like CPU, Memory, and Network usage in both scenarios, it looks like the number of task slots utilised is the same number that is set as the job parallelism. This is regardless of how many task slots are available. Could one of the Flink experts please confirm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The total number of task slots in a Flink cluster defines the maximum parallelism, but the number of slots used may exceed the actual parallelism. Consider, for example, this job:

[image: Flink job]

If run with parallelism of two in a cluster with 2 task managers, each offering 3 slots, the scheduler will use 5 task slots, like this:

[image: Parallelism of two with two task managers with three slots each]

However, if the base parallelism is increased to six, then the scheduler will do this (note that the sink remains at a parallelism of one in this example):

[image: Increase parallelism to six]

See [Flink's Distributed Runtime Environment](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/concepts/runtime.html) for more information.

Comment: This is very interesting indeed, and it explains the discrepancy I observed experimentally. Thank you ever so much for taking the time to post this clear and very detailed answer. I will make sure the number of available slots is identical when comparing different setups, as it does indeed affect the outcome of the processing.