# Difference between job, task and subtask in flink

Tags: apache-flink

I'm new to flink and try to understand:

1. job
2. task
3. subtask

I searched in the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/concepts/programming-model.html) but still did not get it. What's the main diffence between them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Tasks and sub-tasks are explained here -- https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/concepts/runtime.html#tasks-and-operator-chains:

[image]

A task is an abstraction representing a chain of operators that could be executed in a single thread. Something like a keyBy (which causes a network shuffle to partition the stream by some key) or a change in the parallelism of the pipeline will break the chaining and force operators into separate tasks. In the diagram above, the application has three tasks.

A subtask is one parallel slice of a task. This is the schedulable, runable unit of execution. In the diagram above, the application is to be run with a parallelism of two for the source/map and keyBy/Window/apply tasks, and a parallelism of one for the sink -- resulting in a total of 5 subtasks.

A job is a running instance of an application. Clients submit jobs to the jobmanager, which slices them into subtasks and schedules those subtasks for execution by the taskmanagers.

Update:

The community decided to re-align the definitions of task and sub-task to match how these terms are used in the code -- which means that task and sub-task now mean the same thing: exactly one parallel instance of an operator or operator chain. See the [Glossary](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/concepts/glossary.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi @david-anderson, It looks that Task in Flink is equivalent TaskSet or Stage in Spark, while SubTask is equivalent to Task in Spark?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480332/flink-how-does-the-parallelism-set-in-the-jobmanager-ui-relate-to-task-slots

Comment: Task and subtask are most badly designed and implemented both in concept and in code as well. subtask is the smallest unit of work that is run by a thread, but in the Flink source code, there is no class named Subtask or something similar. What is wired, there is a class named Task that implements Runanble, which means Task is the unit that will be run in a thread, this is completely different with the pictures showed above